# How can I configure and send a transaction to the Cardano chain using python

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, smart-contract, api, on-chain

I have written some plutus contracts, but they use parameterisation and the params are gained through a REST API.

I am using python3 to interface with the API, but would like to be able to script an automatic process that converts the data into the params structure, and then submit the plutus code/contract with the params to the blockchain.

I can do the conversion between the REST data and the params, but how do I package the code and submit it to the chain via python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout PyCardano. It is able to serialize python objects to datum and redeemers. Maybe this test example can help: https://github.com/cffls/pycardano/blob/main/integration-test/test/test_all.py#L217 It implements all off-chain code of [forty-two](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week02/src/Week02/Typed.hs) example in Plutus-pioneer-program.

**Update:**

I polished the test into a concrete example with more details here: https://github.com/cffls/pycardano/tree/main/examples/plutus/forty_two

Comment: Do you have any examples of more complex datums being used? I am getting some errors when I try some more complex structures

Comment: @Mateus Checkout this unit test: https://github.com/cffls/pycardano/blob/7ac73501ff3093b1b467b51c685ded3336cdc526/test/pycardano/test_plutus.py#L56 It covers different data structures, e.g. list, map.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, my attempt was a plutus data instance with a map as one of the attributes that has another plutus data instance as the key of that map. Very specific scenario, but it fails for some reason. It says that cborTag cannot be hashable

Comment: Hey @Mateus, we have a discord server. Do you want to discuss the issue you encountered over there: https://discord.gg/qT9Mn9xjgz ?